# CakePHP Pagination leading zeroes

Tags: cakephp, pagination, leading-zero

I've had a request to build pagination that looks like this:

01 | 02 | 03 | 04

Whilst I know how to pad single digits with a leading zero in PHP, I'm unsure how to get this working in the CakePHP Paginator.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the PaginatorHelper class, alias it and overload [PaginatorHelper::numbers()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-PaginatorHelper.html#684-827).

Sadly the numbers() method is huge.

Comment: You're not the first one to encounter this. I haven't had the need myself yet to override it but it's not the first time I see people struggle with it. I've started to refactor this for CakePHP 3.0 in a branch https://github.com/burzum/cakephp/commit/b38b993b5ce84bc12b520c3f4660b5c28f57c028